# What code would make this loop work?

Tags: c++, loops

So here's the question asked to me during an interview -

```
for( blah blah ) { 
   cout<<"World";
}
```

my task was to replace `blah blah` so that the printed output was `:- Hello World !`

And I am only allowed to change the blah blah phrase only , nothing more than that. No code changes below or above that!

Comment: This interview is performing as intended.

Comment: Hint: What can go inside a `for` loop?

Comment: ? and at end cout<<"!" ?

Comment: I can think of at least 3 variants straight of the top of my head - obvious solutions that is. We can then make it more convoluted... ;)

Comment: No.  You need learn C++ better.

Comment: Is the exclamation mark part of the required output?

Comment: Yes "!" is needed in the output!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems to solve.

1. Output in the loop's header
2. Suppress the iteration.

In the first part of a for declaration you can execute almost every single command. So it's a good idea to print here the desired output.

To suppress the iteration just enter `false` as condition. The last part of the header can be left blank.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for ( cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl ; false ; )
    {
            cout<<"World"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Why even worry about the body of the for loop if you can put anything in for `blah blah`:

```
for(int i = 0 ; std::cout << "Hello world!", i < 0;   ) { 
   std::cout<<"World";
}
```

Comment: you could make it even more compact:

for(;std::cout << "Hello World!",0;) { 
   std::cout<<"World";
}

Comment: You forgot the smiley face and the space before the explanation mark. :)

Answer (score 7):

They didn't say you need to actually run the loop, did they?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (int i = (cout << "Hello World!",0); i; ) { cout << "World"; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It took me a little while attempting to control the loop to a single iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (cout << "Hello "; cout; cout.setstate(ios::badbit)) { cout << "World"; }
}
```

If the `!` is meant to be in the output then this code will do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (cout << "Hello "; cout; cout << "!", cout.setstate(ios::badbit)) {
        cout << "World";
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot about the "!" at the end ;)

Comment: @lejlot I assumed that was an exclamation from the OP, not the original question.  The OP can clarify if it's deemed important.

Comment: **+1** for using the `for` body.

Comment: Yeah the "!" is still in the output.BTW thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

How about this for `blah blah`:

```
const char *p = "Hello "; *p; cout << *p, p++); if (1
```

Comment: The closing `)` in `if (1)` must not be part of the "blah blah".

Comment: Otherwise, the whole thing would be `for( const char *p = "Hello "; *p; cout << *p; p++); if (1) ) {`. I.e. the closing parenthesis is already part of the part following the "blah blah".

Comment: @DyP: Ah, yes, gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the for loop is nothing more than a diversion. Look at it like this:

```
for(
/* Your Code Here */
) { cout << "World"; }
```

So, the first thing you need to do is get rid of all of the pesky code already in the program:

```
for(
/* Your Code Begins */
;0;);
/* TODO */
if(0
/* Your Code Ends */
) { cout << "World"; }
```

Since, naturally, they will want to test your cleverness, let us do something very clever next:

```
    for(
    /* Your Code Begins */
    ;0;);
    struct cout {
        void operator<<(cout world)
        {
            hello <world> !"";
        }
        char const* out;
        cout() : out(0) { }
        cout(char const* out) : out(out) { }
        operator bool() { return !out; }
        struct typeof
        {
            typeof(decltype(::std::cout) const&) { }
            void operator>(bool a)
            {
                ::std::cout << (!a ? "!" : "?");
            }
        };
        struct
        {
            typeof operator<(cout c)
            {
                return typeof(::std::cout << "Hello " << c.out);
            }
        } hello;
    } cout;
    if(cout
    /* Your Code Ends */
    ) { cout << "World"; }
```

Note: Since they like the name `cout`, make sure to use it liberally in your code!

Also, be aware of a common GCC bug (well, they call it an "[extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)"), that may cause problems with your absolutely standards compliant c++ code.

Finally, recall that the initial instructions did not call for any newline at the end, so do not expect any. Should the wish to see the output immediately, you may have to [flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) your output.

Some of the hoops that you have to jump through may seem unnecessary, but the rigid requirement that you use a nested class instead of one at namespace level causes some problems with proper operator overloading.

Personally, I would like to point out that this code is very easy to understand: All it does is say `hello <world>!`, so let us just quickly reformat the result a bit, leading to your final code (this time, the surrounding constructs are omitted):

```
    ;0;);struct cout{void operator<<(cout world){

        hello <world>!

    "";}char const*out;cout():out(0){}cout(char const*out):out(out){}
    operator bool(){return!out;}struct
    typeof{typeof(decltype(::std::cout)const&){}void
    operator>(bool a){::std::cout<<(!a?"!":"?");}};
    struct{typeof operator<(cout c){return
    typeof(::std::cout<<"Hello "<<c.out);}}hello;}cout;if(cout
```

Of course, the final step is only done for purely aesthetic reasons and can be omitted if so desired.

P.S.: It actually prints "Hello World!", not ":- Hello World !", which I assume is what the question said exactly. Changing it to conform to the other format is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I may have gone overboard with this... But only slightly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that C++ doesn't recognize spaces!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 0; ++i); if(true){ cout << "Hello World!"; } else { //blah blah ) { 
    cout<<"World";
}
```

Comment: A comment! Nice idea. Shorter: `for( ` + `;0;);cout<<"Hello ";{//` + `) { [new-line] cout<<"World"; }`

Comment: Sadly, it is not correct, since you are missing the closing parenthesis after the "blah blah"

Comment: @dionadar It does say `//blah blah) {`

Answer (score 0):

Nobody bothered to fix the obviously broken code, which access some mysterious never-defined `cout`, which is very obviously horrible code, so ... here's the fix:

```
#include <iostream>

#define BLAH \
  struct { \
    template <typename T> \
    void operator<<(T const& t) const { \
      ::std::cout << ":- Hello " << t << " !\n"; \
    } \
    bool okay;\
  } cout{true}; \
  cout.okay; \
  cout.okay = false

int main() {
  for(BLAH) {
    cout<<"World";
  }
}
```

Only for better readability I part you may change into a separate `#define` called `BLAH`.

Note: My gcc refuses to build this, but clang accepts this with the highest warn-level. I'm building `hw.cpp` like this:

```
make CXXFLAGS=-Wall\ -Wextra\ -pedantic\ -std=c++11 CXX=clang++ hw
```

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: No it's not. The `cout` object is inside the `std` namespace, which you cannot access, without specifying the namespace, too. You have to actively say `using ::std::cout` or `using namespace ::std` in order to make the symbol `cout` visible outside the `std` namespace. Now, **even if** you already did that, nobody prevents you from shadowing iostream's `cout` with your own local variable.